# How can send and receive voice between two raspberry pi3 without use Socket by use java

Tags: java, encryption, raspberry-pi3

How can send and receive voice between two raspberry pi3  without use  Socket
by use java

Comment: Why not use a socket? How are the pis connected? Are they on the same network or are you asking about the options for serial or i2c links? The pi4j project supports those devices

Comment: The project is: - Send an encrypted voice from the first raspberry -by-phone
To the second piece where the second raspberry receives the voice through a telephone connected to it also
There is no contact between the first and second raspberry
Only the first encrypt the sound
The second  decrypts
And  versa

Comment: the project like this http://www.emaraic.com/blog/secure-voice-chat           but  without socket

Comment: I dont get why you dont want to use a socket. that's how you transfer data over a network. You can encrypt data over a socket (using SSL or your own implementation).

Comment: It seems that he's wanting to use a phone instead of a traditional network.  That means he's going to need modems.  That's pretty old-school, and I doubt the data bandwidth will support his use case, but it might.

Comment: 9600 baud is more than enough to send voice over a phone line.  Not sure how encryption will affect the bandwidth needed.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out how to access the Raspberry Pi's serial port, and attach that to a "real" modem.  Then send commands to the modem to dial the other PI which will pick up the remote phone and relay the data to the second Raspberry PI.

Basically you'll be using two modems attached to the phone lines, with a Pi transmitting to the other Pi by going through the first modem, onto the phone line, through the second modem into the second Pi.

The reason you'll need modems?  Because you're planning to use the POTS phone network to transmit digital data.  Modems are built to do that, but the bandwidth available to do so is not large, so you might have difficulty if your encryption requires more bandwidth per second of time than can be received on the other end.